# Route:list works in local machine but gives error on server in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, runtime-error, vps

I was updating my server code and everything worked well, even the migration and seeding.

but when I tried `login URL` it gave me `404` error so I checked and in that process ran then `PHP artisan route: list` command in the terminal.

and got the error as below:

```
PHP artisan route: list

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\UserController] does not exist.

  at /var/www/html/x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
    801|
    802|         try {
    803|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    804|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  > 805|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    806|         }
    807|
    808|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    809|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}()
      [internal]:0

  2   ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\UserController does not exist")
      /var/www/html/x/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

it says the given controller cannot be found. I have personally checked the folder and it exists. the permissions are correct and also if I run the same command in the local machine, I do get the `route list` on the same code.

have tried `composer dump-autoload` and `composer update` still no use of that as the error exists. so what's the real issue here. how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is your local operating system?

Comment: Try the following command: php artisan cache:clear

Comment: my local os is mac. also i tried clearing cache, views and routes on server

Comment: What are your routes?

Comment: normal auth route from laravel

Answer (score 0):

ok found the real issue. it was as below.

```
App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\UserController 

WAS CHANGED TO

App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\UserController
```

I thought only windows are not case sensitive to the `Caps` and `small` character. As using Mac, I was never able to find it.

Just occurred to check the route list as it might be the case sensitivity, and it was. My bad :/